# GitHub Prefill Comment on Issue from URL

Tags: github

You can create a `GitHub` issue from a `URL` by following these [guidelines](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/creating-an-issue#creating-an-issue-from-a-url-query) but I was wondering how I can create a new comment on an existing issue and set the body content from the `URL`?

I have tried: `https://github.com/projecthorus/sondehub-tracker/issues/81?body=new` but that does not work.

Answer (score -1):

I did not find a direct solution so I decided to create a Google Forms and a script that takes the responses and posts these as a comment in the GitHub issue.